# Wrong placement for \preto using etoolbox

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, etoolbox

I'm observing that the adding a text to a list of tables (or figures) through \preto from etoolbox does not work properly when the table is placed on the next page if it does not fit the page where it is set.

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox, tocloft}
\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Chapter}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\\

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\\

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\\

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\\

%blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
  \caption{My table's caption}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c} 
        \hline
        column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
        \hline
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        r1 & r2 & r3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If I left the last comment on "blah blah blah", then the list of tables reads like:

> List of Tables
>
> Chapter 1
>
> 1.1 My table's caption ... 6

If I remove the comment character, then the list of tables gets weird and it reads like

> List of Tables
>
> 1.1 My table's caption ... 6
>
> Chapter 1

If I force the table to be [h]ere it gets solved, however I prefer having tables at top. Can anyone point how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A suggestion: Do us a favor and change your username to something more telling than "user1747493". If you have figures and tables in every chapter you could consider patching `\chapter` instead of `\figure`/`\table`, but this is not a general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better adding the annotation to the chapter making command; with memoir there's the hook `\mempostaddchaptertotochook` for this purpose.

The following code is adapted to an [answer of mine in the GuIT forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/30277-elenco-figure-mancano-titoli-sezioni); as you see, the annotation is printed only if in a chapter some tables (or figures) are found.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\mempostaddchaptertotochook{%
  \addchaptertoloft{lof}%
  \addchaptertoloft{lot}%
}
\def\addchaptertoloft#1{% 
   \addtocontents{#1}{% 
     \protect\xcontentsline{chapter} 
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter\protect\nopagebreak\protect\vspace{1ex}}{}}}
\makeatletter
\def\xcontentsline#1#2#3{\@ifnextchar\contentsline 
  {\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}{}} 
\makeatother


\newcommand{\blah}{%
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah\par}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter}

\blah\blah\blah\blah

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{My table's caption}

\begin{tabular}{l c c} 
\hline
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
\hline
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter}

\blah\blah\blah\blah

\chapter{Chapter}

\blah \blah \blah \blah

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{My table's caption}

\begin{tabular}{l c c} 
\hline
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
\hline
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
r1 & r2 & r3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `center` inside `figure` or `table`, but `\centering`. Also, don't add `\\` at the end of a paragraph.

---

Note that when `hyperref` is used, a different definition of `\xcontentsline` should be used. Change the code above with

```
\makeatletter
\def\xcontentsline#1#2#3{\@ifnextchar\contentsline 
  {\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{}{}}{}} % two {} groups for hyperref
\makeatother
```

(all the rest remains the same). The change is also compatible for when `hyperref` is not used.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves the issue. I'll also take into consideration the comments at the end of your answer.

Comment: By the way, is there any chance to get the chapter name in addition to the chapter number?

Comment: As I commented in the referenced forum topic, I find unnecessary adding “Chapter x”; what would you need the title for?