# list of tables customization

Tags: table-of-contents

I was working with LaTex and wanted to get the following form output for \listoftables tab space is a particular amount of gap. Can any body help me in doing this in following format. I've tried it but it has yielded no result like the needed ones.

```
LIST OF TABLES

Chapter 1

Table 1.1   {tab space}            Name of Table     {tab space}                   Page Number

Table 1.2   {tab space}            Name of Table     {tab space}                   Page Number

Chapter 2

Table 2.1   {tab space}            Name of Table     {tab space}                   Page Number
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you use, are you loading a package such as `tocloft` that simplifies the creation of Tables of Contents (and Lists of Tables). Can every chapter be assumed to contain at least one table?

Comment: The convenience of adding a vertical space (default is done using `\addvspace{10\p@}`) is that it doesn't affect a chapter where you do not have any tables (floats) in it. With an automated approach you would need to count the number of floats in a chapter and conditionally place the `Chapter X` heading. Alternatively, how do you plan on handling chapters without any floats?

Comment: I am using Report type and no extra package. chapters may or may not have a table. its just that.

Comment: I am using Report type and no extra package with the chapters may or may not have a table. Its just it

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167847/wrong-placement-for-preto-using-etoolbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve your objective by (a) using a modified `\chapter` command for those chapters that contain tables (the modifications mainly consist of writing "Chapter `<num>`" to the file `\jobname.lot`) and (b) employing the `tocloft` package to insert the string "Table " right before the table number in the list of tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
  \cftsetindents{table}{0em}{6em}
  \renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table } % prefix "Table " to table number
\newcommand{\tchapter}[1]{%
  \chapter{#1}
  \addtocontents{lot}{Chapter \thechapter} % write 
  \addtocontents{lot}{\medskip} % choose vertical spacing to suit your needs
}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\tchapter{First chapter}

\begin{table}[th!] \caption{First} \centering u \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Second}\centering v \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Third} \centering w \end{table}

\tchapter{Second chapter}
\begin{table}[th!] \caption{Fourth}\centering x \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Fifth} \centering y \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Sixth} \centering z \end{table}

\chapter{Third chapter} % no tables in this chapter, so don't use \tchapter

\tchapter{Fourth chapter}
\begin{table}[th!] \caption{Seventh}\centering x \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Eighth} \centering y \end{table}
\begin{table}[h]   \caption{Ninth} \centering z \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\par\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
   \addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{#1}}
   \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{5pt}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}
\setlength\cfttabnumwidth{5cm}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{table}
\caption{Name of table}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{Name of table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\begin{table}
\caption{Name of table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've patched the `\@chapter` command so to insert the name of the chapter in the LoT

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\par\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
   \addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{#1}}
   \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{5pt}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

and adjusted the parameters for tables with the help of `tocloft` commands

```
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}
\setlength\cfttabnumwidth{5cm}
```

Adjust the last lenght from `5cm` to whatever you need.

Comment: Can your approach deal with chapters that don't contain tables? The OP has indicated in a comment that a given chapter may or may not contain tables.

Comment: @Mico It's not clear to me whether the OP wants to show chapters without tables or not.

Comment: karlkoeller sir i don't want to show chapters which don't have tables but i will do that now from tocloft package study but Really Thanks to you. You helped me a lot and Mico Sir thanks for your help too sir. You guies are great. I don't know when i'll be this much smooth in LaTex and life.